# nvidia 3d vision kit enabling

Tags: nvidia, 3d

I've recently installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS and successfully installed the nvidia driver for my gtx 550ti gpu... my question is, how do I enable the 3d vision since my monitor is 3d capable and I'm always using it for gaming...

thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 3D (stereo) viewing with 3D Vision in Linux is supported only for Nvidia Quadro cards. Quadro series is intended for professional use.

Nvidia FAQ [here](http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2652/kw/linux%20vision/session/L3RpbWUvMTM5NTgxNzQwNy9zaWQvUVNPTVlhUWw=).

In case somebody gets to this question and has a Quadro graphics card then [here](http://www.zib.de/durmaz/3dVision.html) are some good instructions how to get stereo working on linux.